# Projectile trajectory messed up after up scaling sprites

Tags: python, pygame

My screen is 1920 x 1080 and the display that I have drawn everything on is 960 x 540. I have a projectile which does an equation with the position of the mouse to determine its trajectory but because I have up scaled everything the mouse pos is still acting like its 1920 x 1080 and not 960 x 540.

Class method for projectiles trajectory ( I have camera movement which is why player.rect.x is being subtracted by scroll )

```
    def shoot(self, player, mouse_x, mouse_y, speed, scroll):
        self.dx, self.dy = mouse_x - (player.rect.x - scroll[0]), mouse_y - (player.rect.y - scroll[1])
        distance = math.hypot(self.dx, self.dy)
        self.dx, self.dy = self.dx / distance, self.dy / distance
```

Up scaling code

```
surf = pg.transform.scale(display, WINDOW_SIZE)
    screen.blit(surf, (0, 0))
    pg.display.update()  # updates the screen every frame
    clock.tick(FPS)  # caps framerate at 60 frames per second
```

Resolution for screens im blitting on

```
# (0, 0) is in the top left corner of the window
WIDTH = 1920  # 1920 / 15 = 128 (Math for tile map)
HEIGHT = 1080  # 1080 / 15 = 72 (Math for tile map)

TILE_SIZE = 15

WINDOW_SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)

FPS = 60

screen = pg.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)  # Initiate screen
display = pg.Surface((960, 540))
```

The yellow cube is the projectile, that's what it looks like when shot is upscaled

[bullet being shot in 960 x 540](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVhCg.png)

This is what it looks like when shot in 1920 x 1080

[bullet being shot in 1920 x 1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlx4m.png)

in both images, i was clicking right.

Please someone help me to find a fix for the bullet trajectory / mouse pos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just scale the mouse position:

```py
def shoot(self, player, mouse_x, mouse_y, speed, scroll):
   
    mx = mouse_x * 960 / 1920
    my = mouse_y * 540 / 1080

    self.dx, self.dy = mx - (player.rect.x - scroll[0]), my - (player.rect.y - scroll[1])
    distance = math.hypot(self.dx, self.dy)
    self.dx, self.dy = self.dx / distance, self.dy / distance
```

---

Alternatively, you can scale the mouse position after getting it with [`pygame.mouse.get_pos`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html):

```py
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse_pos = (mouse_pos[0] * 960 / 1920, mouse[1] * 540 / 1080)
```

Comment: Oh, yea that makes sense xD. Thanks! Was pretty stumped.